# Plugin for generating the entire audio waveform seekbar?

Tags: after-effects

Is there any plugin or extension for After Effects for generating the entire audio waveform seekbar? I've heard about the audio spectrum visualizer plugins for After Effects, but I haven't heard anything about the waveform seekbar generators. Perhaps this feature is already in After Effects, since I'm not very experienced in working with it. I'm interested in waveform seekbar similar to the soundcloud player or nulloy music player. Otherwise, this may be a simple waveform seekbar: black and white, solid. Plugins can be paid or free, although free is of course better.

Comment: Welcome undergroundsurface :) For only viewing it or for animation purposes?

Comment: Actually, for both purposes. But, I don't need to create something complex with 3D effects and animation. I'm looking for a simple 2D waveform on a black background.

Comment: For After effects this: http://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-sound-keys/  is a solid solution.

Comment: It looks fine, but is quite expensive. Is there a free alternative to it? Maybe not for After Effects.

Comment: Afaik there is no alternative solution for AE. To get an solid answer please add more context to the question to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think if I was going to do this quickly as a one-off, I'd cheat.  I'd open the audio file in an audio editor, like Audition or Audacity, grab a screenshot, then modify that screenshot in Photoshop & AE until I got the look I wanted in After Effects.  If you need a scrolling line through it as it plays, just position a line at the beginning of the waveform, then add some linear position keyframes to move it through the waveform at the right rate. 
It's an ugly hack but for a one-off, it's probably the quickest solution.

Comment: I don't want to create a new thread, but I want to ask this: is it possible to generate a 2D audio waveform with the Blender. As I know, Blender is a free program, but it is most suited for the creation of 3D.

Comment: @undergroundsurface For blender checkout: blender.stackexchange.com. Related questions: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6079/sound-block-buttons/6091#6091, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/rescaling-a-baked-f-curve-to-values-between-0-and-1 or this blendernation post: http://www.blendernation.com/2015/03/19/how-to-create-a-particle-based-audio-visualizer/

Comment: Thanks anyway. It's quite difficult to work with 3D effects so I'll need to learn the basics. As I understood, the Blender doesn't support 2D plugins, effects for compositing video. Blender is useful only for 3D.

Comment: @undergroundsurface Blender is also useful for 2d processing, because you can do editing and image compositing. To drive an animation by sound this could be also useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtD5UQE5Xj0